# How to run chown ant task recursively?

Tags: ant, chown

I want to change ownership of a directory in AIX recursilvely.
I use

```
<osexec commandbase="su" dir="/bin" mode="osexec">
<args>
<arg line="chown -R ${broker_admin_name}:${broker_admin_name} ${broker_installation_directory}/dcx"/>
</osexec>
```

Is this code correct?
I want to change ownership of all the directories and file under dcx including dcx, but I am not able to change the ownership by doing this.I also try:

```
<chown owner="${broker_admin_name}">
<fileset dir="${broker_installation_directory}/dcx" includes="**/*">
</fileset>
<dirset dir="${broker_installation_directory}/dcx" includes="**/*">
</dirset>
</chown>
```

But by this only the directories under dcx have their ownership changed not the files.
Also, Can I do this by normal shell command inside my build.xml?
i.e. `chown -R abc:abc xyz` How can I do this directly in build.xml?

Comment: osexec command is not a standard ANT task...

Comment: I got that working. Actually <osexec commandbase="su" dir="/bin" mode="osexec">
<args>
<arg line="chown -R ${broker_admin_name}:${broker_admin_name} ${broker_installation_directory}/dcx"/>
</osexec> .. In this I forgot to add `<arg value="-c" />`. So, it will be: <osexec commandbase="su" dir="/bin" mode="osexec">
<args>
<arg value="-c"/>
<arg line="chown -R ${broker_admin_name}:${broker_admin_name} ${broker_installation_directory}/dcx"/>
</osexec> .. :)

Comment: I'll repeat.... osexec is not a standard ANT task. Sounds like a custom task, peculiar to your build environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the "Operation not permitted" error message?

## Example

On Ubuntu the chown task is restricted by the OS:

```
$ ant

build:
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build/one/test.txt': Operation not permitted
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build/three/test.txt': Operation not permitted
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build/two/test.txt': Operation not permitted
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build': Operation not permitted
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build/one': Operation not permitted
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build/three': Operation not permitted
    [chown] chown: changing ownership of `/home/mark/tmp/build/two': Operation not permitted
    [chown] Result: 1
    [chown] Applied chown to 3 files and 4 directories.
```

Running the "chown" command demonstrates the same restriction

```
$ chown -R an_other_user build
chown: changing ownership of `build/one/test.txt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `build/one': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `build/two/test.txt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `build/two': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `build': Operation not permitted
```

The best solution is to run ANT as the root user:

```
$ sudo ant
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/one"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/two"/>

        <echo file="build/one/test.txt" message="helloworld"/>
        <echo file="build/two/test.txt" message="helloworld"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="init">
        <chown owner="an_other_user" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="build"/>
            <dirset dir="build"/>
        </chown>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

</project>
```